# stratified sampling R: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, r, sampling, stratifiedjs

I want to use this function [here is the code on github](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/984691) to sample my dataset in 2 parts 90% traning data set ( for example) and 10% (the rest) are the test ( for example  tried this code :

---

```
library(XLConnect)
library(readxl)
library(xlsx)
library(readxl)
ybi <- read_excel("D:/ii.xls")
#View(ybi)
test= stratified(ybi, 8, .1)

 no= (test$ID_unit) # to get indices of the testdataset samples
 train = ybi [-no,] # the indices for training data 


 write.xlsx(train,"D:/mm.xlsx",sheetName = "Newdata")
```

---

in fact my data have 8 attributes and  65534 row.
I have selected by the code above just 10% based on the 8 eigth attribute which is the class it gives me without any problm the test set but not the training data ther error is on the figure (joined)[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI7Zc.png)

how to fix it!

Comment: Where does the error occur?

Comment: in the last instruction once I would like to write the data into excel file for future use q I have joined the error in the figure I sent ( is there any problm you can not see it !!) here is the error msg :                                > write.xlsx(train,"D:/mm.xlsx",sheetName = "Newdata")
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: @RomanLuštrik It seems to be strange since the code is okey and the testing samples it gives me the excel file without any problm but for the 90% of training no excel file ( I suppose maybee it s due to the size !! 10% of  65534 row would be for test and it s okey ( I could be imported without pblm into excel) but not the case for the rest of the data : training samples .

Comment: Please do not use comments to dump code/output. Edit your question and  incorporate all the necessary information you think will help others help you solve the problem. In other words, make your example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you JVM has no enough memory allocated for the heap.

As a quick fix, export system variable _JAVA_OPTIONS

`export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xmx8G -Xms1G -Xcheck:jni"`

you can also use:

`options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8G")`

and set -Xmx to a value that will make R happy.